# Quotient by a torsion group

Tags: abelian-groups

Let $A$ be a finitely generated abelian group of rank $r$. The rank of the abelian group $A$ is the number of copies of $\mathbb Z$. Let $T$ be the torsion subgroup of $A$. Show that $\frac{A}{T(A)}\cong\mathbb Z^r$.

I don't know if it helps but I've managed to show that all the non-zero elements of $T(A)$ have infinite order.

I'm guessing some usage of the FTFAG will bring out the isomorphism but I don't know how to get rid of the $\frac{\mathbb Z}{n \mathbb Z}$ bits.

Comment: I'm confused. What is your definition of "rank $r$"? If you write $A\simeq T(A)\times \mathbb{Z}^r$, isn't this number by definition the rank in which case there isn't anything to show?

Comment: Is $A$ finitely generated?

Comment: Supposing that $A$ is finitely generated, you've probably seen FTFAG stated as $A\cong\mathbb{Z}^r\times\mathbb{Z}/n_1\mathbb{Z}\times\cdots\times\mathbb{Z}/n_s\mathbb{Z}$. Then $\mathbb{Z}/n_1\mathbb{Z}\times\cdots\times\mathbb{Z}/n_s\mathbb{Z}$ is precisely the torsion subgroup of $A$.

Comment: How have you managed to shown that the elements of $T(A)$ have infinite order?! The [torsion subgroup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_subgroup) is precisely those elements of finite order in the group...

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ is a rank one torsion free abelian group, so the statement is generally false. It is true for *finitely generated* abelian groups.

Comment: I've edited to include the definition of rank.

From the two comments that I see, is it literally just "multiplying by the denominator"?

Also, does this mean that $T(A)$ is finite since $\frac{\mathbb Z}{n\mathbb Z}$ is finite? How do we know that $T(A)$ is finite?

Comment: You need to use @NAME if you want people to be notified of your comments. Finitely generated abelian groups have finite torsion subgroups. $T(A)=\mathbb{Z}/n_1\mathbb{Z}\times\cdots\times\mathbb{Z}/n_s\mathbb{Z}$, so it's a *finite* product of *finite* cyclic groups... But I don't understand what your concern is with just applying the fundamental theorem?

Comment: It is true that $T(A)$ is finite, but I don't see why this is relevant to the problem. If it is finitely generated, then by the structure theorem $A\simeq T(A)\times \mathbb{Z}^r$, so killing $T(A)$ just leaves you with $\mathbb{Z}^r$.

Comment: Thanks @WarrenMoore and @Matt! I didn't realise that $T(A)$ is exactly just the finite product of finite cyclic groups. Only just started dealing with these torsion groups. :)

Comment: @DonAntonio I know it's not free! It's *torsion-free*. Probably I should have used a hyphen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To say that the rank of an abelian group is "the number of copies of $\mathbf{Z}$" doesn't quite make sense for abelian groups which are not finitely generated. The rank of an arbitrary abelian group $A$ is by definition the $\mathbf{Q}$-dimension of the $\mathbf{Q}$-vector space $A\otimes_\mathbf{Z}\mathbf{Q}$. As egreg points out in the comments, $\mathbf{Q}$ is an abelian group of rank $1$ without torsion and it is not free of rank one because it is not finitely generated. So it is not true that an abelian group of rank $r$ is free of rank $r$ after taking the quotient modulo the torsion subgroup. For *finitely generated* abelian groups this is true, and follows, for example, from the structure theorem for finitely generated abelian groups (once one verifies that the number of copies of $\mathbf{Z}$ appearing in a decomposition of a finitely generated abelian group into a direct sum of cyclic groups is equal to the rank as defined above).

Comment: Thanks. I'll edit to include that $A$ should be finitely generated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

according to Fuchs, Theorem 15.5 (which holds in some way even for modules over PID, I suppose) a group is finitely generated iff it is a finite direct sum of cyclic groups. So the torsion part, $T(A)$, is finitely generated as well, i.e. bounded. $T(A)$ is always pure and pure bounded subgroups are direct summands, so it has a direct complement, which is torsion-free (every torsion element is in $T(A)$) and finitely generated, hence again direct sum of cyclic groups, this time each of them is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, so $C\simeq\mathbb{Z}^n$. You get: $$A/T(A) \simeq T(A) \oplus C/T(A) \simeq C/(T(A) \cap C) \simeq C/0 \simeq C$$ and you're done.

P.S. The elements in $T(A)$ MUST be of FINITE order!